# What are the highlighted rectangular objects on the SpaceX's CRS 21 Dragon capsule?

Tags: spacex, dragon-v2

What are the rectangular objects seemingly placed where otherwise Super Dracos would be - in this picture of the CRS 21 Dragon 2 capsule?

Reference: https://twitter.com/SpaceX/status/1310962850601545728/photo/1

[image: Picture of Dragon 2 CRS 21 capsule]